# Storing massive amounts of images. Storage schema and consequences? or is there a better way?

Tags: php, image, performance, storage, large-data-volumes

I am working on an auction listing project. Part of that project allows users to upload photos of the items(sometimes hundreds of items) they will have for sale on a given date. So I have multiple questions that all lead to how to do this efficiently and effectively allow easy deletion after the date has passed.

**1.** Folder management: My thought is to give each date its own folder in that folder each user/listing for that day and the listing itself would have its own folder with a unique identifier in case they have multiple listings for the same date. So the folder schema would be:  **date/user/uniquefoldername/images.jpg** Thoughts? Is there a better way keeping in mind that I want to be able to easily delete the folder and it contents after the date has passed?

**2.** Consequences: Its possible that I could have up to 1500 listings on any given date and if each user adds 100 photos(worst case scenario) that is 150,000 for any given date or 4,500,000 in a month(users are allowed to post listings up to a month in advance). Given the schema above what, if any, would be the consequences? Other than large amount of holy crap I need more storage!(We will deal with storage issues as needed).

**3.** Storage and retrieval: My thought is to store only the path to the image folder and then write a script to retrieve all of them for display in a lightbox like setup(think Facebook). Thoughts? Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

**4.** Removal: My thought is to cronjob daily to remove all folders after where at least 24 hours has passed since the date of the listing and then update the database to reflect the removal of the folder to avoid ppl trying to view images that have been removed. Can this be done effectively? Meaning should I do remove them all in one shot or break it up and run it on an hourly basis to avoid overloading the server?

**5.** Is there a better way all around? At some point we will be adding an image server or exploring other storage avenues but until then I need to do this as efficiently as possible to keep the server load a minimum from back end going ons

**6.** Given the scale of data processing and the removal process is this possible to do without sacrificing server performance?

**Some background:** We are looking at roughly 400k page views per day, so 12 million page views a month. We are expecting in excess of 10k members with the capability of posting listings and over well 100k registered users(registration  is only required to view certain aspects of the site) of the general public and 12-15 million unique visitors a year. Each listing when presented to the public will interact with 4 tables in the database, as it is now on paper, obviously this may change as the scope becomes clearer. There will be several cron jobs running daily, 2 of which we see as server intensive, newsletter and photo deletion. The newsletter being extensively interactive with the DB as it will contain zip code spencific data which utilizes a table in the db on a per user basis. So with all this in mind you can see why I am concerned about getting the image storage schema correct the first time.

Comment: At any given time there could be 4.5 million images on the server. Remember they are allowed to upload images for listings a month in advance. Unless my math is wrong(which I suck at btw).

Comment: Hmm... I need to do the sums properly

Comment: ok having done the math, not that I am thinking it is right because it probably isn't, again, I suck at math, you are correct that is just under half a TB of storage. The sticky part and I now realize I forgot to throw this into the mix and I should have, my BAD, is the 12,000,000 page views per month. Now granted this is page views not image views(in lightbox) as I have no firm data to even guess at that number. But I think you can see why I have questions. 400,000 page views a day, and a bad storage schema with 4.5 million images is a a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I agree that ensuring you have enough bandwidth, is a major factor. And a major expense. To get a feel for the cost, I looked at the prices, at Amazon. More sums required to try and work out daily views, peak views etc. Which means 'bandwidth' and 'total daily volumes'. It does at least give you a 'feel' for the 'size' of the issues you are dealing with. And a 'ballpark' figure for the cost per day to run the site.

Comment: The numbers I am using are for a competing site and they are firm numbers with worst case scenarios added in. For example, will every user upload 100 images, no. Will every visitor visit every listing and view the image no, does every day have 1500 listing, no. but you get my drift, trying to be more safe than sorry. Well that and cause a mass exodus from the competing site of course. ;)

But right now all I am really worried about is getting the schema right, there is no going in and changing it with these kind of numbers and traffic. Well I suppose you could but I would rather get it right.